# How to root the Teclast X70 3G Android 4.4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

My device is Teclast X70 3G. Are there any root method known for Android 4.4.4? I did not find anything available after 4.4.2.

Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your device? Or consult [How do I root my device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) first.

Comment: @AndrewT. added device model.

Comment: Does the 4.4.2 method not work?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Windows application which you can use to root your device kingo root it supports all latest android version. Here is the link to download kingo root http://www.kingoroot.org/